# Getting Query String item after htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a re-written URL that will look like one of the following:

```
http://www.example.com/anyfolder/some-more-here/
http://www.example.com/anyfolder/some-more-here/?ref=referralcode
```

Here is the rule I was playing with:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /page.asp?folder=$1&url=$2&refcode=$3 [NC,L]
```

My question is that since (http://www.example.com/anyfolder/some-more-here/?ref=) is a rewritten URL that has an additional query string item on it after the rewrite is done, how do I get that "ref" item in my code?  I can easily get "anyfolder" and "some-more-here" by doing a simple request, but I am confused on the "ref" value part.  I think the QSA flag might be needed, just having trouble bringing it all together.

I am using Classic ASP on this site, but the solution probably applies to PHP as well.

Any help would be great. thank you in advance!

Dennis

Comment: What is the rewrite rule you'r using?

Comment: Oops, sorry. see above.

Answer (score 2):

ok as per your comment you do need `QSA` flag. Try your rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /page.asp?folder=$1&url=$2&refcode=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This will preserve `?ref=...` in the rewritten URI.

- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Comment: LOL - sometimes the answers are right in front of you.  it worked great, thanks for the help!!